# How to compare the words in the line with php?

Tags: php

I am trying to write the php code that goes over the .CSV file and identifies the similar words between the first line and second, first line and third and so one.

My test.csv file is look likes as following:

```
1,"most of the birds lives in the village"
2,"birds in the village are free"
3,"no birds can be trapped in the village"
4,"people of the village are so kind"
5,"these birds are special species where most of them are so small"
```

Note: the numbers as shown in above example is in the test.csv file but they are the key for comparison which it called sentences ID and i will use them in comparison.

So by using the above test.csv file, what i want to do is to compare the line 1 with line 2 and tell how many words are similar and then compare the line 1 with line 3 and tell how many similar word are there and so on, and complete the following format:

1:2 = ?

1:3 = ?

1:4 = ?

1:5 = ?

and

2:3 =?

2:4 =?

2:5 =?

and

3:4 =?

3:5 =?

and

4:5 =?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please, take the [tour].

Comment: provide the PHP code you tried.. or at least any pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another snippet:

```
<?php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));

foreach ($csv as $key => $row) {
    compareLine($csv, $key);
}

function compareLine($csv, $key)
{
    $temp = array_slice($csv, $key);
    foreach ($temp as $index => $row) {
        if ($index === 0) continue;
        $firstWord = $csv[$key][1];
        $secondWorld = $row[1];
        $diff = array_intersect(explode(" ", $firstWord), explode(" ", $secondWorld));
        echo "{$csv[$key][0]}:{$row[0]}" .' = ' . implode(", ", $diff) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amin thanks for code. Is there ways modify your code to count the number of the similar words founded?

Comment: just count $diff variable

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, not perfect but it does the job:

```
// You can use PHP's array_intersect 
function checkSimilarity ($string1, $string2) {
    $arr1 = explode(" ",$string1 );
    $arr2 = explode(" ",$string2 );
    $result = array_intersect(array_unique($arr1) , array_unique($arr2)); //matched elements with duplicates removed
    return count($result); //number of matches
}

$sentences = [
    1 => "most of the birds lives in the village",
    2 => "birds in the village are free",
    3 => "no birds can be trapped in the village",
    4 => "people of the village are so kind",
    5 => "these birds are special species where most of them are so small"
];

// loop through array
foreach ($sentences as $mainKey => $value) {
    // for each number, loop others check similarity
    foreach ($sentences as $key => $v) {
        // if number key exist
        $compareTo = $key + 1;
        if(array_key_exists($compareTo, $sentences) && $compareTo != $mainKey && $mainKey < $compareTo) {
            echo $mainKey . ":" . $compareTo  . " = " . checkSimilarity($value, $sentences[$compareTo]) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Sample sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c571beb140a1dc114b42bfd884fbe33e348f76c5

Comment: Here is what your script it outputting:
`1:2 = 5
1:3 = 5
1:4 = 4
1:5 = 3
2:3 = 4
2:4 = 3
2:5 = 2
3:4 = 2
3:5 = 1
4:5 = 3`

I was not expecting these numbers.  I believe you are matching words like "the" more than once if they appear in a sentence more than once.  If that is not desired, I would suggest using the following function to remove duplicates: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php]